# How to array merge in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a problem here, I want to combine 2 arrays into 1, I've tried using array_merge from php, and merge () from laravel but nothing works 
//$plucked is EAV database

```
$vendor = Vendor::find($id)->toArray();
        $vendor_detail = Vendor_detail::where('vendor_id',$id)->get();
        $plucked = $vendor_detail->pluck('vendor_name','vendor_value');

        $merged = array_merge($plucked, $vendor);

        // $merged = $vendor->merge($plucked)->all(); 
        dd($merged);
```

I think because the array is different,  there array $plucked

```
#items: array:10 [▼
    "user_email" => "cobaupdatelagi@gmail.com"

  ]
```

and there my  array in $vendor

```
array:15 [▼
  "vendor_id" => 39
  "province" => "ACEH"

]
```

the output that I want

```
$somearray =[
   "vendor_id" => 39
  "province" => "ACEH"
  "user_email" => "cobaupdatelagi@gmail.com"

]
```

Comment: what you want in here??expected result here?

Comment: @albus_severus there's my expected result 

$somearray =[
   "vendor_id" => 39
  "province" => "ACEH"
  "user_email" => "cobaupdatelagi@gmail.com"

]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$vendor` is one associative array while `$plucked` is an array of arrays. Even if it has only one item it will be of index zero so you need to loop through `$plucked` and merge for each one.

```
$vendor = Vendor::find($id)->toArray();
$vendor_detail = Vendor_detail::where('vendor_id',$id)->get();
$plucked = $vendor_detail->pluck('vendor_name','vendor_value');

$merged = [];
foreach($plucked as $p){
    $merged[] = array_merge($p, $vendor);
}
dd($merged);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$vendor = Vendor::find($id);
$vendor_detail = Vendor_detail::select('vendor_id','province')->where('vendor_id',$id)->get()->toArray();

$data= array_merge($vendor,$vendor_detail);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use database join to get faster results.

```
$vendor = Vendor::join('vendor_details', 'vendors.id', '=', 'vendor_details.vendor_id')
    ->select('vendors.*', 'vendor_name','vendor_value')
    ->where('id', $id)
    ->first();

if ($vendor)  {
    $vendor = $vendor->toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $vendor_detail = Vendor_detail::where('vendor_id',$id)->get(); will give you a collection
```

as well as        `$plucked = $vendor_detail->pluck('vendor_name','vendor_value');` will give you a collection, so, either you can use collection [merge](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-merge) or you may like to loop through one and add merge another as other answer is doing, but these are not array, you are getting collections.